# How to draw straight line between nodes on two curves?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-node

In essence I believe my problem lies with trying to specify a node a certain distance along the x axis. I want ideally for a straight, vertical line to be draw between two nodes on two curves. However I am having trouble first specifying the node on the curve and I don't want to be doing in analytically if I have a choice. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{near start abs/.style={xshift=1cm}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,bend right]
  \node (a) at (-2,3) {};
  \node (b) at (0,1) {};
  \node (c) at (2,3) {};
  \node (p1) at (-3,-3) {};
  \node (p2) at (0,-1) {};
  \node (p3) at (3,-3) {};
  \draw[->] (a) parabola bend (b) (c) coordinate[pos=0.5](A); % attempting to specify position along line for top curve
  \draw[->] (p1) parabola bend (p2) (p3) coordinate[pos=0.5](B);% attempting to specify position along line for bottom curve
  \coordinate (b1) at ($ (b)!.5!(c) $); % attempting to specify coordinate along line for top curve
  \coordinate (b2) at ($ (p2)!.33!(p3) $); % attempting to specify position along line for bottom curve
  \draw [<->] (b1) -- (b2) node [sloped,midway,above] {1cm};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B) node {1cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where this produces:

[image]

however, what I am trying to produce is something more like this. I also made this in tiki but did so manually specify the start and end point of the line with coordinate instead of nodes and would like to avoid this if possible to make it more versatile. I have been stumped on this for a while so any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is draw function and then calculate its value at given `\x`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto, 
      > = Straight Barb,
samples = 51]
\draw[->, semithick]   plot [domain=-2:2] (\x, {+0.5+0.2*(\x)^2});
\draw[->, semithick]   plot [domain=-3:3] (\x, {-0.5-0.2*(\x)^2});
%
\draw[<->]  (1,{-0.5-0.2*(1)^2}) to ["\qty{1}{cm}", sloped]   ((1,{0.5+0.2*(1)^2});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Because in your MWE you load `intersections` library, let me add solution using it and any curves:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                intersections,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, > = Straight Barb]
\draw[->, semithick, name path=A]   (-2,+2) .. controls +(0.5,-1) and +(-1,-1) .. (2,+1);
\draw[->, semithick, name path=B]   (-2,-2) .. controls +(0.5,+1) and +(-1,+1) .. (2,-2);
%
\path[name path=C] (1,2) -- (1,-2);
\coordinate [name intersections={of=A and C, by=a}];
\coordinate [name intersections={of=B and C, by=b}];
\draw[<->]  (b) to ["\qty{1}{cm}", sloped]   (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Im quite new to using latex and tikz so this might not be the "best" way, but here's how I attempted to do the picture on the bottom!

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{near start abs/.style={xshift=1cm}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,bend right]
  \node (a) at (-2,3) {};
  \node (b) at (0,1) {};
  \node (c) at (2,3) {};
  \node (p1) at (-3,-3) {};
  \node (p2) at (0,-1) {};
  \node (p3) at (3,-3) {};
  \draw[-] (a) parabola bend (b) (c) coordinate[pos=0.5](A); % attempting to specify position along line for top curve
  \draw[-] (p1) parabola bend (p2) (p3) coordinate[pos=0.5](B);% attempting to specify position along line for bottom curve
  \draw[<->] (1.5,2) -- (1.5,-1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gave

[image]